# How to list posts with an order ? - In Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Here is my code:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now().order_by('-published_date'))
```

I want to list the post with an order here. However when I run the server, I am getting error like this:

```
'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'order_by'
```

I am watching some udemy course so I am doing whatever he do. Can someone help me about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis **`)`** after `timezone.now()`. Add a closing parenthesis and it will be resolved.

`return Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')`

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted

Comment: An good editor with syntax highlighting can help you spot syntax errors.

Comment: i am using pycharm but it didnt spot my problem